# Перенести уведомления из шторки в программу?

Tags: android, уведомления

Мне нужно из шторки переписать уведомления в программу. Как получить данные активных уведомлений? Наверняка вопрос детский, но я только учусь.. Два дня рою интернет на эту тему - ничего внятного найти не могу.
Надеюсь кто-нибудь удосужится выложить код сюда.. android api 21

Comment: [`getActiveNotifications()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#getActiveNotifications())?

Comment: Не могу разобраться как использовать сиё. Может быть есть ссылочка на кусок кода?

Comment: Буду чрезмерно благодарен!  Мозг уже сломал на этом месте.

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть [сюда](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-notificationlistenerservice-example.html).

Comment: Как раз на этом примере я и ломаю голову.. Там только тикет получается выдернуть из уведомлений. А как остальное получить, не могу допереть..  ->   **i2.putExtra("notification_event",i +" " + sbn.getPackageName() + "n");**   - вот, но тут только PackageName

Comment: Разобрался.  **sbn.getNotification().extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_***   Спасибо за наводку!

Comment: @post_zeew Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: @IgorAndreev По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Comment: Не ожидал, что мой "детский" вопрос может быть ещё кому-то полезен :)  Сейчас сформулирую и дам "сам себе" ответ основываясь на достигнутом результате.

Answer (score 0):

По ссылке https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-notificationlistenerservice-example.html готовая программа, которая умеет выводить packageName висящих в трее уведомлений.
Можно добавить: sbn.getNotification().extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT) - строка содержащая текст уведомления,
sbn.getNotification().extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE) - строка с заголовком уведомления.

По имени packageName, из примера по ссылке выше, можно выдернуть информацию о приложении конкретного уведомления (чтобы получить имя приложения и иконку уведомления)

```html
            String packageName = intent.getStringExtra("packageName");           //получаем имя пакета, для запуска нужного приложения
//            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), packageName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//            Intent intent1 = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);


            try{
                PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, GET_META_DATA);
                String appName = packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(context.getPackageManager()).toString();
                String appVersion = packageInfo.versionName;
                int appVerCode = packageInfo.versionCode;
                Drawable app_icon = packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(context.getPackageManager());
                txt.setText("Имя: " + appName + " " + txt.getText());
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Everybody knows shit's fucked..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
```